# How to Split *MULTIPLE* image into tiles? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, image

I want to split **multiple** images into tiles(it must be div or similar). (With Javascript or jQuery.)

and Images should be one below the other.

Its my div;

```
<div class="reading-content">                                               
    <div class="page-break no-gaps">
        <img id="image-0" src="image.jpg" class="some-class">
    </div>
    <div class="page-break no-gaps">
        <img id="image-1" src="image1.jpg" class="some-class">
    </div>
</div>
```

example jsfiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/0Lxr2tad/

```
var img = new Image();
var length = 30;
var ylength = 20;
img.onload = function() {
    var width = this.width,
        height = this.height,
        _length = -length,
        i, j;

    // create a <div/> with all basic characteristics, to be cloned over and over in the loops below.
    var $basicDiv = jQuery('<div/>', {
        class: 'splitImg',
        css: {
            'width': Math.floor(width/length),
            'height': Math.floor(height/ylength),
            'background-image': 'url(' + img.src + ')'
        }
    });
    // Finding a node in the DOM is slow. Do it once and assign the returned jQuery collection.
    // Also, #wrapper's width can be set here.
    var $wrapper = $('#wrapper').width(width + length * 2); 
    
    for (i = 0; i > _length; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j > _length; j--) {
            $basicDiv.clone().css({'background-position': `${width/length * j}px ${height/ylength * i}px`}).appendTo($wrapper);
        }
    }
}
img.src = 'http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg'; // how to do multiple this??
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do it again after a long time and I was able to do it yesterday, anyone can use it. ( You can remove `.splitImg { some style }`  class for remove spaces. )

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/s3yhjLg7/1/)

```js
let i = 0;
let seenUrls = new Set()

setInterval(() => {

let url = document.querySelectorAll('#someid p img')[i].src;
let image = document.querySelectorAll('#someid p')[i]
let gor = document.querySelectorAll('#someid p')


if (!seenUrls.has(url)) {
seenUrls.add(url)

    var img = new Image();
    var length = 5;
    var ylength = 5;
    img.onload = function() {
        var width = this.width,
            height = this.height,
            _length = -length,
            i, j;

        // create a <div/> with all basic characteristics, to be cloned over and over in the loops below.
        var $basicDiv = jQuery('<div/>', {
            class: 'splitImg',
            css: {
                'width': Math.floor(width/length),
                'height': Math.floor(height/ylength),
                'background-image': 'url(' + img.src + ')'
            }
        });
        // Finding a node in the DOM is slow. Do it once and assign the returned jQuery collection.
        // Also, #wrapper's width can be set here.
        var $wrapper = image;
        image.style.width = width + length * 2 + "px";
        
        for (i = 0; i > _length; i--) {
            for (j = 0; j > _length; j--) {
                $basicDiv.clone().css({'background-position': `${width/length * j}px ${height/ylength * i}px`}).appendTo($wrapper);
            }
        }
    }
    img.src = url

    i = (i + 1) % gor.length;
    
}

}, 50)
```

```css
#someid {
    max-width: 100%;
}

#someid p {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#someid p img {
    display: none!important;
}

.splitImg {
  padding: 1px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someid">
  <p>
  <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Responsive-Touch-Friendly-jQuery-Gallery-Lightbox-Plugin-lightGallery.jpg" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use jquery much so I can suggest javascript option like this:

```
const targetElement = document.querySelector(...) // I choose the div that we are going to append newdivs
```

I don't know if it exists but I assume there is an array of content you use for src urls or any other data.

```
let arrayOfInfo = [{},{}] // this is a hypothetical array of objects that we will use  

arrayOfInfo.forEach(obj => {
let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList.add("page-break","no-gaps")
    newDiv.innerHTML=`<img id="image-${obj.index}" src=${obj.url} class="some-class">`
   
targetElement.append(newDiv);

})
```

so with that approach you automate everything. If you need to reuse, you can make it into a function and run it wherever you need. It is also handy if you need to change some content later on, so you only change the array values and rest goes auto again.

I hope this was what you need.

Comment: Deniz bey istediğim şey tam olarak bu değil, div'imde verdiğim gibi üst üste 2 görselim var diyelim, ben o görselleri tek tek parçalara bölmek istiyorum. Attığım JsFiddle'ı incelersen ne demek istediğimi anlarsın.

Comment: Yani örnekteki olduğu gibi ilk görseli css ile görünmez yapıyorum veya kaldırıyoruz, sonra görseli background-image kullanarak parçalara bölüyoruz benim istediğim şey bu background-image'in src'sinde hepsinin linki olması lazım ayrı ayrı yapabilmek mümkünse yardımcı olabilirsen sevinirim.

Comment: Şu anki örnekte img.src tek link alabiliyor. for ile loopa soktuğumda sonuncu linki alıyor.

Comment: Eger kodun tamami calisiyorsa, o zaman tek yapmaniz gereken, ayni kodu bir kez daha sadece oteki url ile calistirmaniz lazim.  onu da tum codu fonksiyon icine koyup, farkli url ile 2 kez calistirmaniz yeter

Comment: yani soyle 
`function imageSplitter (url){
// use the code that works 
img.src= url;
}  
imageSplitter(url1)
imageSplitter(url2)
`

Comment: İşte hocam o url'leri siteden nasıl çekeceğiz tek tek, onu bulmam lazım. Linkleri elle girmeyeceğim otomatik çekilecekler

Comment: O zaman sorunu biraz daha netlestirmen lazim. Cunku soru basligindan bu anlasilmiyor.
Yapman gereken, kopyalamak istedigin imagelari iceren sayfaya gir. tum imagelari tutan elementi bul. querySelectorAll ile nodeList al. nodeListi forEach methodu ile tum elementlerin urllerini oku. okuduklarini olusturacagin yeni bir arrayin icine gonder. boylece bir url arrayi elde etmis olursun. sonra da fonksiyonunu yine bir array methoduyla tekrar tekrar calistirirsin

Comment: Yardımların için çok teşekkür ederim, anlatsan da yeni olduğum için nasıl yapacağımı bilmiyorum müsait olduğun bir zamanda kodla desteklersen sevinirim, iyi akşamlar dilerim.

Comment: Rica ederim.Sen kendi kodunu gosterirsen yardimci olabilirim. Bende asiri tecrubeli sayilmam. Ogrenmenin en iyi yolu, parca parca ilerlemek. Yazdigim adimlari sirayla yapmaya calis. ilk olarak googlea how can I select a div yaz mesela. onu ogrendikten sonra diger adima gec, boyle tamamlarsin. Zaten baska bir yolu da yok